# Python 2.7.9 Can not kill subprocess while running script

Tags: python, menu, popen, pause

I want to run strandtest.py after running test.py for 5 sec. When I get an input from my remote strandtest.py has to stop so I can go on in the menu again. it's like a screensaver in windows. I can start a subprocess after 5 sec. but when it runs i can't stop it. I tried p.kill() and p.terminate() but they both won't work.

*os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)*

gives

*module' object has no attribute 'pid'*

Can you help me?

Here's my code

```
import lirc
import time
import os
import signal
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
import subprocess
from neopixel import *

Volume = 60
mute = False
bool = False
bool2 = False
LEDS = 100
PIN = 18
BRIGHTNESS = 255
R     = 255
G     = 255
B     = 255
LED_CHANNEL    = 0
LED_STRIP      = ws.WS2811_STRIP_GRB

sockid=lirc.init("lifetec", blocking = False)
strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(10, PIN, 1050000, 10, False, BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL, LED_STRIP)
strip.begin()

def VolumeUp(procent, Bool):
    if Bool == False:
        if procent < 100: 
            Procent = procent + 4
            os.system('amixer -c 1 set Speaker ' + str(Procent) + '%')
            os.system('aplay /share/Wav/Menu/beep-22.wav')
            return Procent
        else:
            os.system('amixer -c 1 set Speaker ' + str(procent) + '%')
            os.system('aplay /share/Wav/Menu/button-3.wav')
    return procent

def VolumeDown(procent, Bool):
    if Bool == False:
        if procent > 0:
            Procent = procent - 4
            os.system('amixer -c 1 set Speaker ' + str(Procent) + '%')
            os.system('aplay /share/Wav/Menu/beep-22.wav')
            return Procent
    return procent

def Mute(Bool):
    print(str(Bool))
    os.system('aplay /share/Wav/Menu/beep-22.wav')
    os.system('amixer sset Speaker toggle')
    os.system('aplay /share/Wav/Menu/beep-23.wav')
    if Bool == False:
        Bool = True
    else:
        Bool = False
    print(str(Bool))
    return Bool

def wheel(pos):
    """Generate rainbow colors across 0-255 positions."""
    if pos < 85:
        return Color(pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3, 0)
    elif pos < 170:
        pos -= 85
        return Color(255 - pos * 3, 0, pos * 3)
    else:
        pos -= 170
        return Color(0, pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3)

def rainbow(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=1):
        for j in range(256*iterations):
            print("JJJJ = " + str(j))
            for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, wheel((i+j) & 255))
        strip.show()
        #time.sleep(0.01)
Gettime = True
pause = False

while True:
    if Gettime == True:
        timenow = time.time()
        print("timenow Gettime")
        print(timenow)
        Gettime = False

    if time.time() - timenow >= 5:
        if pause == False:
            print time.time() - timenow
            print("pause")
            bool = True
            pause = True
    if bool == True:
        p = subprocess.Popen('python strandtest.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        bool = False
    if bool2 == True:
        gelukt = os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        Gettime = True
        print(gelukt)
        bool2 = False

    codeIR = lirc.nextcode()
    if codeIR != []:
        if codeIR[0] == "KEY_VOLUMEUP":
            print codeIR[0]
            print Volume
            Volume = VolumeUp(Volume, mute)
            print Volume
        if codeIR[0] == "KEY_VOLUMEDOWN":
            print codeIR[0]
            print Volume
            Volume = VolumeDown(Volume, mute)
            print Volume
        if codeIR[0] == "KEY_0":
            print codeIR[0]
            print Volume
            mute = Mute(mute)
            print Volume
        if codeIR[0] == "KEY_POWER":
            print codeIR[0]
            os.system("/share/RadVanAdvontuur.py 100 255 255 0")
        if codeIR[0] == "KEY_PAGEUP":
            print codeIR[0]
            bool2 = True
            pause = False
    if codeIR[0] == "KEY_PAGEDOWN":
            print codeIR[0]
            bool = True
            print "script running"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run it directly without a shell, like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('python strandtest.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

then you can use p.kill() or p.terminate() to end the process.

Comment: When I run it without a shell it come with an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 94, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen('python strandtest.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: You may need to indicate the whole path to strandtest.py